# Sphinx extension to use GitHub markdown emoji in Sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx, emoji, github-flavored-markdown

#### Problem

I have been using [(Python) Sphinx doc](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/), along with [CommonMark](http://commonmark.org/) parser, to write Sphinx documentation containing files written in both reStructuredText and Markdown. So far so good, it works really fine ([see this line in an example of Sphinx `conf.py` file](https://bitbucket.org/lbesson/web-sphinx/src/master/conf.py?fileviewer=file-view-default#conf.py-157)).

However, CommonMark's support for GitHub flavored Markdown (GFM) is not perfect, and one important feature it lacks are **emoji**.
I searched for other Markdown parser, more specific to GFM, for instance [py-gfm](https://py-gfm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but none of them seem to support emoji.

> For instance, the screenshot below shows the Sphinx output on the left, and the GitHub rendered version on the right:
>   [image: an example]

#### So my question is:

- Does anyone know a Sphinx extension that could add support to GFM-like emoji, in rST and/or Markdown? (ie, emoji written like `:boom:` this).
- Or a trick I could use to convert any emoji, eg, `:boom:`, to a small image? (as that's what GitHub is doing anyway, see for instance [the `:boom:` image](https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/icons/emoji/unicode/1f4a5.png)) The trick should probably be on the HTML pages created by Sphinx, not on the source Markdown files (I want them to still be readable with GitHub file viewer).

Thanks in advance.
Regards.

---

#### 2 partial solutions

- A partial solution is [this small Python script](https://bitbucket.org/lbesson/bin/src/master/emojize.py) I wrote, using [carpedm20's emoji](https://github.com/carpedm20/emoji/) package.
  It will convert any :emoji: alias (written :like_this:) to it's UTF-8 version, if possible.
- I also tried to use [pymdownx.emoji](https://facelessuser.github.io/pymdown-extensions/extensions/emoji/) package, to write [this second script](https://bitbucket.org/lbesson/bin/src/master/emojize_pngorsvg.py).
  It will convert any :emoji: alias to a piece of HTML code loading a distant PNG (or SVG) version (from JsDelivr's CDN). Still not perfect, the size/scaling is not good, and even emojis in ... are replaced. (I will improve this).

Both can be used with this tiny Bash for loop:

```
BUILDDIR=_build/html  # Adapt to the location of your Sphinx output
for i in "$BUILDDIR"/*.html; do
    emojize.py "$i" > "$i".new
    # or emojize_pngorsvg.py "$i" > "$i".new
    wdiff -3 "$i" "$i".new;
    mv -vf "$i".new "$i"
done
```

Demo:

- With UTF-8 codes for emojis:
  [image: an example 2]
- With PNG images for emojis (still not perfect):
  [image: an example 3]

Comment: Did you find something interesting since you asked? Still looking in 2019 and I have not found anything (I too am trying to avoid declaring a `|substitution|`).

Comment: Hi @Peque, sadly no, I haven't find any new tools (but I haven't actively looked for it). I'm still using the same hack script in production for https://smpybandits.github.io/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did not find anything out there, so ended up [creating an extension](https://github.com/sphinx-contrib/emojicodes).

Install it with:

```
pip install sphinxemoji
```

Then, in your Sphinx's `conf.py`:

```
extensions = [
    '...',
    'sphinxemoji.sphinxemoji',
]
```

Then you can start using emoji codes in your documentation (note you need to use bars around the emoji code though):

```
This text includes a smily face |:smile:| and a snake too! |:snake:|

Don't you love it? |:heart_eyes:|
```

If you want consistent emoji style, you can add this to your `conf.py`:

```
sphinxemoji_style = 'twemoji'
```

Comment: This is great. How can one write a decent piece of user doc without a single emoji is beyond human comprehension.

Comment: This is awesome 

Comment: One should add that it works for .rst files but don't handle .md files (CommonMarkParser)

Comment: I have been trying to get this answer working on `.md` files with the Myst parser, completely removing `.rst` support and only having `.md` support. I have left detailed info of what I've tried on [issue #40](https://github.com/sphinx-contrib/emojicodes/issues/40) if anyone wants to have a look please  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to convert the emoji to a small image or use an extension, because Sphinx actually supports emoji as they're copy-pasted right out of the box.

If you copy any emoji and add it to a doc file, your editor might not show it correctly, but as long as the emoji was inserted it should show up in your doc.

Try it out with the siren emoji:

I know this works for reStructuredText files, so hopefully it should work for Markdown files too.

One thing to make this easier is to put substitutions for all the emoji you want to use in your [rst_epilog](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/config.html#confval-rst_epilog) for the reStructuredText files. This way you can use something like this in the epilog:

```
.. |siren| replace::
```

Every time you'd want to use a siren in your reStructuredText documents, you just use `|siren|`.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks, but that's not exactly what I was aiming at...

- I know emojis can be entered directly in the source, but 1. I don't want to copy and paste them constantly (eg. from emoji-cheat-sheet.com), 2. I want to write pure ascii files to avoid encoding nightmare, 3. I like how GitHub renders emojis written with `:siren:`.

- And using rst_epilog and alias is good if you have a small number of alias, but I would like to have support for all emojis, without having to define 600 aliases. Also, it probably doesn't work for .md files read with commonmark parser (rst_epilog is for .rst).

Comment: Unfortunately, I think my answer is the closest you can get to useable emoji.  One thing you could try to do is fetch all the name information for each emoji, as well as its artwork, then write an extension in Sphinx that parses something like `emoji:\`emoji-name\`` into the relevant file with that name.

Comment: PyMdown (e.g., for MkDocs) has this extension: https://facelessuser.github.io/pymdown-extensions/extensions/emoji/, and Sphinx can use PyMdown instead of Recommonmark for reading and using Markdown documents. And there is a Python module to convert from ascii aliases (:emoji:) to UTF-8 code, https://github.com/carpedm20/emoji/. I will try to write a small post-processor (or a durty bash script) to convert from ascii emoji to UTF-8 code in the HTML output produced by Sphinx.