# Sphinx Read the Docs - Use icon-only in texts

Tags: html, css, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I want to use some informative icons that depict specific meanings. Hover your mouse over an icon and you see a tooltip showing what it means.  Allow non-graphical user agents (e.g. browsers that do not support CSS, text-to-speech devices) to read it too.

Consider you write a list

- Chicken sandwich
- Tofu sandwich - vegan
- Chicken salad
- House salad - vegan

and you want to change this as below, where  means *"vegan"*.

- Chicken sandwich
- Tofu sandwich -
- Chicken salad
- House salad -

One idea I come up with is to write

```
* Chicken sandwich
* Tofu sandwich - &&VEGAN&&
...
```

then replace the string `&&VEGAN&&` with `<span class="vegan">VEGAN</span>`,

Also add custom CSS snippets

```
span.vegan {
    display: none;
}

span.vegan:hover {
    visibility: visible;
    /* some position settings for the tool tip go here */
}

span.vegan::before {
    display: inline;
    font-family: "Font Awesome";
    content: "\f06c";
}
```

The string replacement can be done every time I perform `make html` followed by a shell command

```
find /path/to/build/html/ -name *.html -exec \
  sed -i 's/\&\&VEGAN\&\&/\<span class="vegan"\>VEGAN\<\/span\>/g' {} \;
```

Does Sphinx or Read the Docs already have this sort of feature?

Comment: Writing a custom ReST directive would be the obvious feature you’re looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sphinx extension to use GitHub markdown emoji in Sphinx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42087466/sphinx-extension-to-use-github-markdown-emoji-in-sphinx)

Comment: No, the emoji icon in the example " To-Do" is used as "decorative", i.e., even if some user agents (e.g. text-to-speech) fail to show this icon, readers still see the text "TO DO". The example in the question "Tofu Sandwich - " is different. Without this "informative" icon readers can't tell if it is vegan (food).

Comment: @deceze - If you are confident with your answer, could you post it as an Answer?  "Using informative icons as if it were icon-only GUI is not part of Sphinx' standard product feature as of version 2.3; you need to make a custom ReST directive". <- this is good enough.  And of course if you have an even better answer, please post.

Answer (score 0):

Create a (custom) directive. Use `replace::` to put some other texts, `image::` to put an image, and `unicode::` to put a (special) Unicode character.

In the original question, I wanted the cucumber character represents every `|vegan|`. Create the following directive in the same reStructuredText source document or the `rst_prolog` in `conf.py` which allows you to apply this directive in entire documents.

```
.. |vegan|  unicode:: U+1F952
```

```
* Chicken sandwich
* Tofu sandwich - |vegan|
* Chicken salad
* House salad - |vegan|
```

Run `make html` and open the created HTML file with a browser. You will see a result like below:

[image: Example result on Firefox 73.]

**Restriction:** Simply replacing directive texts by another texts or images will leave web accessibility concerns.

As stated in the original question, none of these directive methods can have the `title` attribute. In the HTML file, you will want to replace `|vegan|` by the following HTML code:

```
<span title="Vegan">&#x1f952</span>
```

The example directive will only makes . On a web browser, hover your mouse over the cucumber character and you will see a tooltip  saying *"Vegan"*. It will also allow you to see the meaning of this character even if your browser doesn't support some special characters including that emoji.

*Workaround 1.*  Make HTML anyway and replace the text by a desired one.  Find and replace every cucumber character by the HTML code. In Bash, use

```
find /path/to/build/html/ -name *.html -exec \
  sed -i 's//<span title="vegan"><\/span>/g' {} \;
```

*Workaround 2.*  Use different directives for each output format type.  (In research. Someone answer [StackOverflow: "Sphinx: Use a different directive for a different output format"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60439235/sphinx-use-a-different-directive-for-a-different-output-format).)