# Sphinx: Use a different directive for a different output format

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, rst2pdf

Assume you have a reStructuredText document and want to export it in two formats using Sphinx 2.x: HTML and PDF.

You want to put some slightly different contents in these two formats. For example, the text *"I am HTML"* appears in the HTML version whereas *"I am PDF"* appears in the PDF version in the same location of the document.

Use a replace directive like below will give you *"I am HTML"* regardless of the export format.

```
.. |foo| replace:: HTML

⋮

I am |foo|
```

Can you use a different directive for a different export format?

Comment: Does the "raw" directive do what you want? https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#raw-data-pass-through

Comment: No, I want to use the same representation text (like ``|foo|``).  Imagine you have 1,000 |foo|s in your documents and you want to define what it is in a single place, maybe in the prolog in conf.py.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little clunky, but it works for me:

```
.. role:: latex(raw)
   :format: latex

.. role:: html(raw)
   :format: html

.. |foo| replace:: :latex:`LaTeX text`:html:`HTML text`
.. |bar| replace:: :latex:`other latex text`:html:`other html text`
```

Comment: Did it really work? The PDF output shows _both_: ``|foo|`` and ``|bar|`` were replaced by ``LaTeX textHTML text`` and ``other latex textother html text`` respectively ☹  I used rst2pdf.  I replaced all ``latex`` by ``pdf`` in the example script but it didn't help.  The HTML looks ok.

Comment: It worked when I built a LaTeX document and also when I built PDF using `pdflatex`. I didn't try `rst2pdf`.

Answer (score 1):

A solution could be to define a [`rst_prolog`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-rst_prolog) (or `rst_epilog`) dynamically based on some [*tag*](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html#cmdoption-sphinx-build-t).

`conf.py`:

```py
prolog_for_html = """
.. |document_type| replace:: HTML
"""

prolog_for_latex = """
.. |document_type| replace:: latex
"""

if tags.has('html_prolog'):
    rst_prolog = prolog_for_html
elif tags.has('latex_prolog'):
    rst_prolog = prolog_for_latex
```

`document.rst`

```
This is a |document_type| document.
```

`Makefile`

```
html latex:
    sphinx-build -t $@_prolog -b $@ src build/$@
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it couldn't be the _builder_ tag: [These standard tags are set _after_ the configuration file is read, so they are not available there.](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-only) It'd have to be an explicitly-defined tag, as you demonstrated above.

Comment: @FeRD Thanks for the comment. I removed this from the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Sphinx's "[only directive](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#including-content-based-on-tags)" should be your friend.

Note that this does not work in plain Docutils (where you may use the [strip-classes](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/user/config.html#strip-classes) configuration setting and class values like "no-html" to emulate the effect of `.. only:: not …`.