# Sphinx rst2pdf and role directives

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, rst2pdf

In a reStructuredText on Sphinx 2.x, I want to put a content that changes depending on the output format.

In any source document, say, index.rst, add the following lines:

```
.. role:: pdf(raw)
   :format: pdf

.. role:: latex(raw)
   :format: latex

.. role:: html(raw)
   :format: html

.. |foo| replace::
   :pdf:`PDF!`
   :latex:`LaTeX!`
   :html:`HTML!`

I am |foo|
```

I expect it shows *"I am HTML!"* when the output format is in HTML, *"I am LaTeX!"* if it's LaTeX (even after converting the product to PDF via pdflatex) and *"I am PDF!"* if it's PDF.

I make the HTML version using `make html` and I see only *"I am HTML!"* in a web browser as I expect:

[image: A make html result]

Install `rst2pdf`. Put the following lines in `conf.py`:

```
extensions = [
    'rst2pdf.pdfbuilder'
]

pdf_documents = [(
    'index',
    u'testRst2Pdf',
    u'Test Title',
    u'Sarah Author')]
```

Make the PDF version with

```
sphinx-build -b pdf ./source/ ./build/
```

*Update.* Below is the output. No error. I ran this using WSL 1 (Ubuntu 18.04).

```
Running Sphinx v2.4.3
loading pickled environment... done
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [pdf]: targets for 1 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
looking for now-outdated files... none found
processing testRst2Pdf...
index
resolving references...
done
writing testRst2Pdf...
done
build succeeded.
```

I see *"I am PDF! LaTeX! HTML!"* that includes all the three items.

[image: An rst2pdf result]

Is there any way to get either *"I am PDF!"* or *"I am LaTeX!"* in the PDF file?

*Note.*

- Before reporting this behavior as a bug, someone help me check if it's unexpected behavior or as-designed.
- This question is derived from the other I asked earlier: [StackOverflow: "Sphinx: Use a different directive for a different output format"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60439235/sphinx-use-a-different-directive-for-a-different-output-format/60440546?noredirect=1#comment106925678_60440546).

Comment: You might also ask on the Google group sphinx-users.

Comment: rst2pdf is not Sphinx. It might not support all its directives. Do you see any warnings or errors, or can you enable them?

Comment: No, no error.  Please search this page with "Update. Below" and see the result I just added a minute ago. Would you recommend XeLaTeX better?

Comment: I could reproduce this, the 3 substitutions appear instead of 1 when building with _rst2pdf_.

Comment: Was there any update on this in 2022? I have been figuring out this from quite a long time.

Answer (score 0):

rst2pdf does not really have conditionals, but you might find the --strip-elements-with-class switch useful? Put the optional pieces into a class name and then if that class doesn't make sense for this format, remove it with the switch.

Manual is here https://rst2pdf.org/static/manual.html#command-line-options and I also blogged (basically a longer version of this first paragraph) about this https://rst2pdf.org/static/manual.html#command-line-options if more information would be useful.